# header function is not working on online server

Tags: header

I have been having problem with header(); This script was generated by dreamweaver login. why will it work on some hosting company and do not work on the company i m hosting?

I have notice that header() do not work on my hosting company at all on all my pages. why do i have this problem?

```
if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.2) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
} else {
    session_regenerate_id();
} 

 //declare two session variables and assign them 
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername; 
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;  

if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) { 
    $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];     
} 
header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess ); } 
else { 
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed ); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code. Also, are you calling this in PHP I assume?

Comment: if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.2) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl']; 
    }
   header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}

Comment: It would be better to edit the question and insert the code there so you can properly format it :-)

Comment: I m trying to do that but i do not know why i can not save the code scott

Comment: I have edited the question and inserted the code so you can accept the edit. I'm not sure if the code you pasted looks right though, there seems to be a problem with the brackets on the last if/else statement.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a problem with the brackets around the header() calls:

```
if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.2) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);
} else {
    session_regenerate_id();
} 

//declare two session variables and assign them 
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername; 
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;  

// changes made below <------
if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) { <--- && false needs fixing
    $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];     
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
} else { 
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginFailed ); 
}
```

Edit - the `&& false` in the if statement will also always fail, this needs to be resolved.

Comment: what is the problem with the bracket?

Comment: It appears that the statement wasn't wrapped properly. I had altered it to how I think it should be, take a look and see the difference.

Comment: hmmm do you mean there is nothing wrong with the header() and its the if statement that is having this trouble? my worries is, i have the same problem on all my pages. where  ever i have header(), it will not work. i upload my site on a testing server at 00webhosting. everything work perfectly just like it works on localhost. i contact my hosting company they try to resolve the problem for almsot 2 weeks not they do not know why i m having this problem. what is your advice Scott?

Comment: You can't have any output at all before the call to header(). No echo, no html, no anything. Ensure this is the case as this will prevent the header() call working. When you say it doesn't work, does the redirect not happen? Do you get any errors? Can you check your CGI error log and see if there are any problems reported?

Comment: There is not error message on error log. the redirect does not happen at all. But if i use java script, on other pages it will redirect.

Answer (score 1):

add that  code below  after `<body>`

```
ob_start();
```

add that code below before `</body>`

```
ob_end_flush();
```

and voola problem solved. ^_^